# Reformat object with map without underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object

```
myObject = {
  1010: "Some label",
  1020: "Another label",
}
```

I'm using `_.map` like this

```
var generateOptions = function ( object ) {
  return _.map( object, function( value, key ) {
    return {
      value: key,
      label: key + ' - ' + value
    };
  } );
}
```

It used to work with underscore's `_.map` but I want to use the built-in function `map`. I have tried

```
var generateOptions = function ( object ) {
  return object.map( function( value, key ) {
    return {
      value: key,
      label: key + ' - ' + value
    };
  } );
}
```

but it seems the `map` function is only for array.

What can I do to get the same result?

Comment: Use `Object.keys` to extract keys from an object, then go the regular way. Be wary, though, of ordering.

Comment: It would be useful to include what you expect the result of the `map` function to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var myObject = {
  1010: "Some label",
  1020: "Another label",
};


var generateOptions = function ( object ) {
  return Object.keys(object).map( function( key ) {
    return {
     value: key,
       label: key + ' - ' + object[key]
    };
  });
}

console.log(generateOptions(myObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the object a `map` function using `prototype`.

```
Object.prototype.map = function(callback) {
    var thisObj = this;
    return Object.keys(thisObj).map(function(key) {
        return {
            key: key,
            value: thisObj[key]
        };
    }).map(callback);
}
```

This will allow you to call `map` on any object and treat it as an array of keyvalue pairs.

In your case, it would be:

```
var generateOptions = function ( object ) {
  return object.map(function( keyValue ) {
    return {
      value: keyValue.key,
      label: keyValue.key + ' - ' + keyValue.value
    };
  });
}
```